# Increment an onscreen counter with a ruby/gosu window

Tags: ruby, click, increment, libgosu

I am trying to make a very simple click counter and I am stuck on getting the click  counter to increment, both onscreen and in the code itself.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gosu'

module ZOrder
    BACKGROUND, MIDDLE, TOP = *0..2
end

WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
    def initialize
        super(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, false)
        @background = Gosu::Color::WHITE
        @button_font = Gosu::Font.new(20)
        @info_font = Gosu::Font.new(15)
    end

    def needs_cursor?
        true
    end

    def draw
        Gosu.draw_rect(0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, @background, ZOrder::BACKGROUND, mode=:default)

        Gosu.draw_rect(50, 50, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::MIDDLE, mode=:default)
        Gosu.draw_rect(50, 150, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::MIDDLE, mode=:default)

        @button_font.draw("Click me", 65, 65, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
        @button_font.draw("Reset", 75, 165, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)

        @info_font.draw("Clicks: #{counter}", 160, 50, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
    end

    def counter
        i += 1
        i
    end

    def mouse_over_button?(mouse_x, mouse_y)
        if ((mouse_x > 50 and mouse_x < 150) and (mouse_y > 50 and mouse_y < 100))
          true
        else
          false
        end
    end

    def button_down(id)

        case id
        when Gosu::MsLeft
          if mouse_over_button?(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            counter
          else
            counter
          end
        end
    end


end

GameWindow.new.show
```

I am aware that my issue most likely lies in the 'counter' function and the 'button_down' function however I have been unable to figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close to having it! You need to add `@counter = 0` to initialize. Then change your `def counter` to that shown bellow

```
def counter
    @counter += 1 
end
```

To get your reset button to work we can now make another procedure called `def reset` as shown bellow

```
def reset
    @counter = 0  
end
```

Then to make it all work change your `def mouse_over_button?(mouse_x, mouse_y)` to the following:

```
def mouse_over_button?(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if  ((mouse_x > 50 and mouse_x < 150) and (mouse_y > 50 and mouse_y < 100))
      return_value = 1
      return return_value
    elsif ((mouse_x > 50 and mouse_x < 150) and (mouse_y > 150 and mouse_y < 200))
      return_value = 2
      return return_value
    end
end
```

Finally change the `def button_down(id)` to the following:

```
def button_down(id)
    case id
    when Gosu::MsLeft
     if mouse_over_button?(mouse_x, mouse_y) == 1
        counter
      elsif  mouse_over_button?(mouse_x, mouse_y) == 2
        reset
      end
    end
end
```

All the right ideas were there! Nice work! If you are unsure why any of this was done, please just let me know and I am happy to explain it further! Hope I helped :)

Comment: This is great. Thanks